# Do I need to Separate Business Objects and Business Logic? Asp.net MVC with Repository Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repository

I'm having trouble finding an answer to this. Basically, right now I have these layers:

- Data Access Layer (where my repositories are). It has Namespace Hello.Data
- Business Layer (where my business objects are). It has Namespace Hello.Business

My repositories will return business objects. For example, GetCustomer will return Customer.

However, in my business layer, I also want to add logic that will use the repository to add/update/delete records, so I can reuse those methods in my MVC controllers. This doesn't work though, since I can't have my Data Access Layer reference my Business Layer and also have my Business Layer reference my Data Access Layer. (It creates a circular reference that is not allowed).

What do you guys think is the best solution? Should I put my Business Logic into it's own project?

So instead of:

```
Hello.Data
Hello.Business
```

I'll have:

```
Hello.Data
Hello.Business
Hello.BusinessLogic
```

Or am I thinking about this all wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Separation would be good because your DataLayer should not need to know any of your other components/layers.

Comment: Perhaps a project called Common or DataClasses, or Domain... There I can store the shared objects that both my data and business layer can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you separate business logic from business models?  The logic should be *in* the models.

The business logic layer shouldn't have to reference anything, aside from maybe small common utility libraries.  Basically, it should have no dependencies on infrastructure concerns (like application technologies, database technologies, etc.).  It should contain *just* business logic.

All other layers should reference the business logic layer.

> This doesn't work though, since I can't have my Data Access Layer reference my Business Layer and also have my Business Layer reference my Data Access Layer.

Correct!  The mistake in this design is that the business logic layer references the data access layer *at all*.  It shouldn't.

It *should*, however, contain *interfaces* for data access (and other infrastructure concerns) which are *implemented* by the data access layer.  The business logic layer only needs to know about the interfaces, it doesn't know or care what implements those interfaces.

A dependency injection container would then be used to connect implementations to interfaces.

- The application layer references the dependency injection layer to initialize it and pass the container (which itself implements a generic business logic interface) to the business logic layer.
- The dependency injection layer references the business logic layer to know about the interfaces and references the data access (and other infrastructure) layer to know about the implementations.
- The data access (and other infrastructure) layer references the business logic layer to know about the interfaces to implement.
- The business logic layer doesn't reference anything.  It requires a configured dependency injection container and uses that container to get implementations for interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In my situation I want to create a method that will delete a file on the server and then delete the record in the database (i.e. calls the repository method). Where would I put that type of method? Should it be in a Util/Helper class library?

Comment: @user1005793: The database and the file system are both infrastructure dependencies.  They would implement interfaces in the business logic, which is invoked by application logic.  There are many ways to do it, but essentially the application logic would do nothing more than receive user input and invoke an operation in the business logic.  The business logic would then know that the data is stored in two different dependencies and would invoke the delete operations on the interfaces for those dependencies (one for the file system and one for the database).